# VMWare Workstation 11: Cant copy/cut/paste between my host Windows 7 and a guest Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, vmware-workstation

I have a bad time trying to understand whythe copy/cut/paste between my host OS "Windows 7" and a Guest OS "Windows 10" don't work!
The feature works with other Guests (WS2012, WS2008 and Ubuntu distro) installed on the same VMWare.

I checked the vmtools, the latest version in installed.

Any hints/explanations how it works with some guests and no with others ?
What can I do to solve the issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just go to vertual machine setting and set connection type as bridge, if you it is in NAT or Host only network it might not work.